# Attenuation and capacity

Tags: signal, wireless, signal-theory

Does attenuation affect capacity for multiple narrowband signals? For example, assume there exists a 20 MHz channel with two 10 MHz subchannels. The first subchannel has frequency response 2 and the second frequency response 1. The total transmit power is 1 across the whole channel with total noise power 1, with the noise distributed evenly across the wideband channel. To my knowledge, the Shannon-Hartley Theorem states that this would just become:

C = sum(Blog2(1+SNR)) = (10000*log2(1+S1/0.5)) + (10000*log2(1+S2/0.5))

Thus, we would distribute signal power evenly as that would maximize capacity. Is there more to it I'm not understanding? It seems to me like the different attenuations of the subchannels might make it so that signal power should be unevenly distributed.

Answer (score 0):

You're 100% on spot. Maximization of the overall channel capacity in the "multiple independent identical power-sharing AWGN channels" scenario is achieved through even distribution of power.

You will also see that if we write down your "how much power to put where" problem a bit more formally,

\begin{align}
\vec P_\text{opt} &= \arg\max_{P_1, P_2} \,C\\
&=\arg\max_{P_1, P_2} \left[
   B_1\log_2\left(1+\frac{P_1}{N_0\cdot B_1}\right)
+  B_2\log_2\left(1+\frac{P_2}{N_0\cdot B_2}\right)
\right],\\
\text{where}&\text{ $B_1 = B_2=:B$ are the subchannel bandwidths, and considered constants}\\
&=\arg\max_{P_1, P_2}\left[
   B\log_2\left(1+\frac{P_1}{N_0\cdot B_1}\right)
+  B\log_2\left(1+\frac{P_2}{N_0\cdot B_2}\right)
\right]\\
&=\arg\max_{P_1, P_2}\left[
   \log_2\left(1+\frac{P_1}{N}\right)
+  \log_2\left(1+\frac{P_2}{N}\right)
\right]\\
\text{and} &\text{ the power sharing constraint $P_2=P-P_1$ applies,}\\
&=\arg\max_{P_1}\left[
   \log_2\left(1+\frac{P_1}{N}\right)
+  \log_2\left(1+\frac{1-P_1}{N}\right)
\right]\\
&=\arg\max_{P_1}\,2^{
   \log_2\left(1+\frac{P_1}{N}\right)
+  \log_2\left(1+\frac{1-P_1}{N}\right)
}\\
&=\arg\max_{P_1}\left[2^{
   \log_2\left(1+\frac{P_1}{N}\right)}
\cdot
2^{
\log_2\left(1+\frac{1-P_1}{N}\right)}
\right]\\
&=\arg\max_{P_1}\left[
\left(1+\frac{P_1}{N}\right)\left(1+\frac{1-P_1}{N}\right)
\right]\\
&=\arg\max_{P_1}\left[
1^2+\frac{1-P_1}{N}+\frac{P_1}{N}+\frac{P_1}{N}\frac{1-P_1}{N}
\right]\\
&=\arg\max_{P_1}\left[
1^2+\frac{1-P_1+P_1}{N}+\frac{P_1}{N}\frac{1-P_1}{N}
\right]\\
\end{align}